# How to use Singular Value Decomposition for time series?

Tags: time-series, eigenvalues

I want to represent a time series using the SVD algorithm. Below are some representations from this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/shan_zindabad/time-series-data-mning-techniques).

[image: time series representations]

The SVD representations is formed by summing k "eigenwaves" corresponding to the first k eigenvalues. But how can I compute the first k eigenvalues when the time series is a one dimensional vector (n*1 matrix)?

When I apply [SVD](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/SingularValueDecomposition.html#getSingularValues%28%29) to a one dimensional vector I get only one eigenvalue.

Comment: You need multiple time series for SVD.  See http://www.cs.bu.edu/~gkollios/dm07/LectNotes/TSIndexing.ppt, for instance (slides 49-56).

Comment: So to understand, I need to have at least k time series for every class of time series and SVD is applied to a class of time series and not to a single instance. But then how can I classify a new time series? For classification I need to compute the distance between the eigenvalues of the unknown time series and the eigenvalues of the known time series.